When using MudSelect within a MudDialog, they don't close after themselves with the MudDialog scrollbar set to approximately middle of dialog
Two issues exist when using MudBlazor selects.

Select's don’t close, after themselves when dialog scrollbar set to middle of dialog.
When scrolling up and down page, select item options become detached from control.

MudBlazor Playground Example

